Check if specific string is present and paste 1 or 0 to specific column
I have data.frame like that:
data <- structure(list(Run = c("AC4", "AC1", "AC3", "AC5", 
                                "AC5", "AC3", "AC1", "AC5", "AC5", "AC1", "AC3", "AC4", 
                                "AC6", "AC6", "AC6", "AC3", "AC2", "AC2", "AC3", "AC4", 
                                "AC1", "AC2", "AC5", "AC5", "AC1", "AC6", "AC5", "AC3", 
                                "AC2", "AC1"), Names = c("Clement", "Mark", 
                                                                   "Dave", "Tim", "Tim", "Gregg", "Greg", "Marcus", 
                                                                   "Nate", "Gregg", "Dave", 
                                                                   "Sonya", "Mark", "Justine", "Mark", 
                                                                   "Marcus", "Marcel", "Mark", "Mark", "Justine", "Marcus", "Marcel", 
                                                                   "Greg", "Tom", "Howard", "Sonya", 
                                                                   "Dave", "Dave", "Tim", "Tim"
                                )), row.names = c(1L, 27L, 36L, 49L, 74L, 89L, 102L, 110L, 121L, 
                                                  132L, 147L, 156L, 172L, 184L, 192L, 198L, 209L, 221L, 230L, 238L, 
                                                  250L, 266L, 278L, 294L, 303L, 320L, 329L, 338L, 347L, 354L), class = "data.frame")

I would like to create a data.frame where I use all unique Names as rows and each ACX is a separate column. Then check if specific Name is present in specific ACX and if yes then paste 1 to appropriate column and row. Is looping the only way ?

with(data[!duplicated(data), ], table(Names, Run))

gives
         Run
Names     AC1 AC2 AC3 AC4 AC5 AC6
  Clement   0   0   0   1   0   0
  Dave      0   0   1   0   1   0
  Greg      1   0   0   0   1   0
  Gregg     1   0   1   0   0   0
  Howard    1   0   0   0   0   0
  Justine   0   0   0   1   0   1
  Marcel    0   1   0   0   0   0
  Marcus    1   0   1   0   1   0
  Mark      1   1   1   0   0   1
  Nate      0   0   0   0   1   0
  Sonya     0   0   0   1   0   1
  Tim       1   1   0   0   1   0
  Tom       0   0   0   0   1   0

or vice versa.

Use table after unique
> t(table(unique(data)))
         Run
Names     AC1 AC2 AC3 AC4 AC5 AC6
  Clement   0   0   0   1   0   0
  Dave      0   0   1   0   1   0
  Greg      1   0   0   0   1   0
  Gregg     1   0   1   0   0   0
  Howard    1   0   0   0   0   0
  Justine   0   0   0   1   0   1
  Marcel    0   1   0   0   0   0
  Marcus    1   0   1   0   1   0
  Mark      1   1   1   0   0   1
  Nate      0   0   0   0   1   0
  Sonya     0   0   0   1   0   1
  Tim       1   1   0   0   1   0
  Tom       0   0   0   0   1   0

